# emberjs - Testing - click on a link with a link-to helper

Tags: javascript, testing, ember.js, mocha.js

I try to implement some tests on my app.

When i do a `click(".on-action-element")`it works very well, but when i try to do same on an element built with the `{{#link-to}}`helper i have this error

```
Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: You have turned on testing mode, which disabled the
run-loop's autorun. 
You will need to wrap any code with asynchronous side-effects in an
Ember.run
```

I 've tried to do :

```
it('can click on link', function (done) {
    Ember.run(function() {
        click('a:contains("demo")');
    });
});
```

but with the same result. What i miss ?

Comment: Ok i've found my mistake i 've put a bad setTimeout instead of using Ember.run.later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All code in setup should be wrapped into Em.run

```
setup: function () {
  Em.run(function () {
    //code to prepare environment
  });
}
```